# jetpack compose: @Preview is unresolved after updating to alpha08

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I updated compose libraries from `alpha07` to `alpha08`

```kotlin
version = "1.0.0-alpha08"
androidx.compose.ui:ui:$version
androidx.ui:ui-tooling:$version
```

But after that `androidx.ui.tooling.preview.Preview` is unresoved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checking out the [release note of alpha08](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/ui#declaring_dependencies) in Jetpack compose, you'll notice that **`ui-tooling` has been moved from `androidx.ui` to `androidx.compose.ui`**

Changes you need to make:

```
dependencies {
    // New dependencies
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha08"
    testImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test:1.0.0-alpha08"

    // Old dependencies
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha07"
    testImplementation "androidx.ui:ui-test:1.0.0-alpha07"
}
```

Comment: you should use : 
testImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test:1.0.0-alpha08" instead of implementation

Answer (score 0):

you mean using :

```
dependencies {

// New dependencies
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta02"
testImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test:1.0.0-beta02"

// Old dependencies
implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha07"
testImplementation "androidx.ui:ui-test:1.0.0-alpha07"
}
```

And using

```
android {

//....

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
    useIR = true
}
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerVersion "1.4.31"
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-beta02"
}
}


tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach 
{
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

but this doesn't fix the problem for me.

Top gradle :

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-alpha16"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31"
 }
```

i didn't find any solution for now using last compose dependencies versions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by :

- Using the latest [Android Studio Artic Fox (Canary build)](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) and not any other canary old IDE.
- Use Android studio Artic Fox Embeded JDK (openjdk version "11.0.8") or download and replace 1.8 java by OpenJdk 11.
- Update dependencies as above.

in this case all are good and all compile ,

Voila,

Answer (score 0):

The latest tooling dependency which worked for me is

```
 implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.2.0-alpha07"
```

I am using

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 27, 2021
```